# Can't verify domain ownership azure website to add subdomain

Tags: azure, dns, azure-web-app-service, cloudflare

I followed this tutorial to add a custom domain on my Azure Website https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain#cname and I can navigate successfully to root domain, my problem is that I want to add a subdomain (www) but at least step I receive next notification:

[image: Error on Azure]

the error is clear that I need to add the CNAME record to point to azure website, the major problem is already added on cloudflare:

[image: Configuration on Azure]

I have something wrong with my configuration?

Comment: how long ago was that? it usually takes anywhere between 5 minutes to a couple of hours to propagate

Comment: more than a week jaja

Comment: well, try using a txt record to verify it or try fixing you typos

Comment: 'the major problem is already added on cloudflare' I dont understand this sentence

Comment: @Jay The major problem indicated by 1st picture is the lack of CNAME card, however, the card have been created in cloudflare, which is Cami's DNS provider.

Comment: if I were you, I would remove cloud fare from the equation (I have never used cloud fare so I cannot speak for that) and see if you can get the subdomain to work. At least that way, we can isolate where the problem is.

Comment: I got the solution, please review the answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found the solution, is only disable for a moment the orange cloud > verify ownership on Azure > et voilà!, subdomain is verified.

Comment: So true... I got that fooling topic recently as well :-)

Comment: works really well and took me waay too long to figure out. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You only need two CNAMEs:

1. **awverify** pointing to **awverify**.thename.azurewebsites.net
2. **www** pointing to thename.thename.azurewebsites.net

[image]